# Differences between two columns having missing values in one

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, brackets

This is my database example in longitudinal way containing:

1. id = Individuals
2. grup_int = categorical variable of group
3. gen = variables to be measured
4. time = point in time for id and gene
5. value

```
        id grup_int gen   time   value
     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 60801001        1 adrb2 2     2.11  
2 60801001        1 ccl2  1     0.941 
3 60801001        1 ccl2  2     0.248 
4 60801001        1 ccl3  1     5.65  
5 60801001        1 ccl3  2     NA
```

What I want to do in my whole database is substracting variables from time = 2 minus time = 1 grouped by id and grup_int --> something like this:

```
df %>% dplyr::group_by(id, gen) %>%  dplyr::mutate(d_post_pre =  value [time == 2] - value [time == 1])

`d_post_pre` must be size 1, not 0.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: id = 60801001, gen = "adrb2".
```

As you can see for the **adrb2** gen, there is no even entry for time == 1, and because of that is throwing this error. The possibilities to be found in value are:

- Missing values in any time point as in "adrb2"
- NAs in any time point as in "ccl3" , this shouldn't matter

Can you suggest any option to perform the line to be shielded from missing values or just paste some text or string to be filtered out?

Thanks in advance!

```
df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(60801001, 60801001, 60801001, 
60801001, 60801001), label = "Identificador", format.spss = "F9.0", display_width = 14L), 
    grup_int = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), format.spss = "F2.0"), 
    gen = c("adrb2", "ccl2", "ccl2", "ccl3", "ccl3"), time = c("2", 
    "1", "2", "1", "2"), value = c(2.1098254, 0.94088, 0.24778089, 
    5.6529145, 0.06939283)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this? Use `pivot_wider` to define `value` columns for `time == 1` and `time == 2`, and then you can simply subtract the columns. Then you can convert to long format again.

```r
df |> 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c("id", "grup_int", "gen"),
    names_from = "time",
    names_prefix = "time_",
    values_from = "value"
  ) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(d_post_pre = time_2 - time_1) |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = c("time_1", "time_2"),
    names_to = "time",
    names_prefix = "time_"
  ) |>
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(value)) |> 
  dplyr::select(id, grup_int, gen, time, value, d_post_pre, everything())

# # A tibble: 6 × 6
#         id grup_int gen   time    value d_post_pre
#      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 60801001        1 adrb2 2      2.11       NA    
# 2 60801001        1 ccl2  1      0.941      -0.693
# 3 60801001        1 ccl2  2      0.248      -0.693
# 4 60801001        1 ccl3  1      5.65       -5.58 
# 5 60801001        1 ccl3  2      0.0694     -5.58
```

Comment: It works. But if I wanted to stay in the long format, which I do for future operations, there should be an option to explicitly say that for id =60801001 and gen = adrb2, there's NO entry in time = 1. Thanks

Comment: @JavierHernando I've updated the answer to convert back again to long format. Also, I've added an alternative that is more similar to your approach, but converts missing values to 0. For example, if there's no row for time 1 for a given id x gen, the value used in the subtraction will be 0. Is that useful? Or you need NA in that case?

Comment: there is no way to know that the d_post_pre value for adrb2 is not just a difference and just the value for time == 2. If I run this in many rows, I cannot check which one is a result of a true substraction and which one is just one of the values

Comment: @JavierHernando ok, that's why I was asking. So the second approach is not useful to you, but the first one converting to wide and then back again to long does yield the results you're seeking.